# count the time in different mode of a user during his login session

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to store user login time.

After login, there are 4 modes
1. available
2. break
3. traning
4. email

When user select 1 of these modes, the timer of that modes start increasing.

then need to store logout time.

At admin end... admin can check the total timing of users in all individual modes.

So the question is that how to add timer and how that timers time changes in the database in 1 second interval?

Comment: What exactly do you mean, store "logout" time? You can implement a javascript time, from a user end. To update the database, it depends exactly how to you want to set it up.

Comment: Do you want the database to input data every second, or would you like to log an initial time, as well as an end time, and then work with the difference.

Comment: want to store latest login n logout time in database.
and during user session, store all timing of each mode.
for example... after login i m in available mode, the timer start like this 1sec, 2sec..., at the time of 10 sec, i changed my mode to email, after 20 sec i resumed again on the available mode, the timer will from the last time of available mode i.e.  starts with 11 sec, 12sec.... like this

Comment: To do something like this, it would be best to utilize jQuery to make calls to your database. On click would send data to your database, as well as update the timer flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

get unix timestamp when user starts any mode and get unix timestamp when user stops. Subtract the former from latter to get total time

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [PHP time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Set the initial link to input the current time. Upon logout, you will also log the time. Subtract the logout time, from the initial logon time.

As far as labeling the modes, you may set it up so that every individual mode has a different variable.